# AS3 Events Handler Error #1069: Property update not found

Tags: actionscript-3, eventhandler

I made this function according tutorial in youtube by: PointClickWin

```
public function Ship (){

    trace ("made ship")
    (1) addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnter);

}

function onEnter( (2) e:Event){

}
```

and in my Game Class like this

```
var ships = new Array();
public function Game()
{
    trace("Made A Game");
    ships = new Array();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
}

function loop(e:Event)
{
    if (numChildren<10)
    {
        var s = new Ship();
        addChild(s);
        s.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        s.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
        s.rotation = Math.random() * 360;

        ships.push(s);

    }

    for (var count=0; count<ships.length; count ++)
    {
        (3) ships[count].update();
    }
}
```

so, in this case pointclick say's that he want to manually updating the loop function in the ship class from the Game class, And he remove the eventlisteners in the ship class he put the coment like this //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop); and put the .update(); after ships.[count] finnaly the function became like this

```
function onEnter () {

}
```

i got an error at

Game/loop() 
this is the error message " ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property update not found on Ship and there is no default value.
 at Game/loop()"

Any Body can Help Me?? Please , Thankz
oww in parentheses () im just put a point to be understanding for anybody.

Comment: Your class `Ship` doesn't have a function called `update`. There are 2 ways to solve this. 1) rename the `onEnter` class to `update`. 2) instead of `ships[count].update()` write `ships[count].onEnter()`

Comment: thankyou verymuch , that's solve my problem now, Thankyou @DodgerThud